# Optimize simple C++ function to minimize copying

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I've been coding C for almost 20 years and figured I should learn C++. As a starting point I wrote the following trivial code to generate the powerset of a set. I'm hoping that some experienced C++ coder could help me with three things:

1. Identify non-idiomatic constructions.
2. Explain where I'm doing unnecessary copying of objects
3. Any other simplifying comments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
vector<vector<T>> powerset(vector<T> s)
{
  // Return the powerset containing the empty set
  if(s.size() == 0) {
    vector<int> dummy;
    return vector<vector<T>> { dummy };
  }

  T v = s.back();
  s.pop_back();

  // Recursively generate powerset for s setminus v
  vector<vector<T>> pss = powerset<T>(s);
  // This is the basis for the current powerset set
  vector<vector<T>> ps = pss;

  for(auto&& i : pss) {
    // Add a set with v added for each set
    i.push_back(v);
    ps.push_back(i);
  }

  return ps;
}

int main(void)
{
  vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4};

  vector<vector<int>> ps = powerset<int>(v);

  cout << "Powerset contains the following elements:" << endl;
  for(auto&& i : ps) {
    for(auto&& j : i) {
      cout << j << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor detail: Don't put `void` in the declaration of parameter-less functions. C++ does not requires it, so it is just code clutter. E.g.: `int main()` instead of `int main(void)`.

Comment: OK, that's good to know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A few things about your code that you could improve:

- There is an error in `powerset`: while it works fine with your test case, you specifically try to return an `std::vector<int>` when `size` is `0` while you should be returning an `std::vector<T>`.
- You don't even need the `dummy` vector. You can take advantage of uniform initialization and brace initialization in a `return` statement to simply write this:

  ```
  return { {} };
  ```
- Using `s.size() == 0` in a condition is fine, but the idiomatic way to do it would be to use `s.empty()`. While it does not make a big difference for `std::vector`, some implementations of `std::list` still implement a \$O(n)\$ `size` while `empty` will always be \$O(1)\$ (C++11 requires `std::list::size` to be \$O(1)\$ but not all implementations are up-to-date). Using `empty` will be better if you ever need to change the kind of collection you use.
- Since `pss` won't be used after the last `for` loop of `powerset`, you can safely move the elements out of it instead of copying them:

  ```
  for(auto&& i : pss) {
    // Add a set with v added for each set
    i.push_back(v);
    ps.push_back(std::move(i));
  }
  ```

  The vectors in `pss` will be moved into `ps`, but left in a valid state, so you don't have to fear errors or undefined behaviour.
- Every time you call `powerset`, you copy a full `std::vector` while you only need to read the elements. Instead of a vector, you could pass iterators so that you don't have to endlessly copy vectors that you only need to read:

  ```
  template<typename T>
  vector<vector<T>> powerset(typename vector<T>::iterator first, typename vector<T>::iterator last)
  {
    // Return the powerset containing the empty set
    if(std::distance(first, last) == 0) {
      return { {} };
    }

    --last;
    T v = *last;

    // Recursively generate powerset for s setminus v
    vector<vector<T>> pss = powerset<T>(first, last);
    // This is the basis for the current powerset set
    vector<vector<T>> ps = pss;

    for(auto&& i : pss) {
      // Add a set with v added for each set
      i.push_back(v);
      ps.push_back(std::move(i));
    }

    return ps;
  }
  ```

  This is not the prettiest in the world, but it works, and you should even be able to generalize the agorithm so that it takes any `BidirectionalIterator` instead of mere `std::vector<T>::iterator`.

Comment: Good review as always.  You might also want to point out that the range-for used for printing would normally use `const auto &` rather than the current `auto &&`.  We don't need to move the items or alter them -- just to print them.

Comment: Picking on a minor detail, since C++11 `list::size()` is required to be constant time (O(1)). I don't have a reference to the standard at hand, but [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size) is up-to-date on that.

Comment: @glampert That's why I wrote "some implementations". I thought that I also wrote "still implement" but I didn't do it, my bad.

Comment: Thank you. I had correctly identified the correct places, where copying happened, but didn't know exactly how to easily get rid of it. One question: if this was a divide-and-conquer algorithm and I want to recursively call something with the upper and lower half, how do I calculate the iterators? Is it just regular pointer arithmetic or is there another idiomatic way?

Comment: One more question: What does std::move(i) actually do? It must somehow change the type in order to call some "move" version of push_back(). However, it seems like magic how you would implement it such a "type changer".

Comment: @Edward: What are the semantic differences between `const auto&` and `auto&&`? Google seems to have trouble with the `&` signs, so finding anything useful seems tricky.

Comment: @JT1 `std::move` simple does `return static_cast<T&&>(value);`. It casts the value to an rvalue reference. Therefore, if a function has an optimizaed rvalue-reference overload, it will be called.

Comment: Pointer semantics and iterator semantics are close (by design). You should probably be able to implement a divide-and-conquer algorithm if you use random-access iterators (`std::vector`, `std::deque` and `std::array`).

Comment: Concerning `const auto&` vs `auto&&`, this is tricky: `auto&&` will deduce the type and use the [reference collapsing rules](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html) and preserve constness. Using `const auto&` allows to *add* constness but only deduces the decayed type.

Answer (score 7):

`vector<vector<T>>` is fairly specific to a powerset and cumbersome to write. Instead you could use a `typedef` and a more specific function name.

```
template<typename T>
using powerset = vector<vector<T>>;

template<typename T>
powerset<T> createPowerset(vector<T> s)
{
  if(s.size() == 0) {
    vector<int> dummy;
    return powerset<T> { dummy };
  }

  T v = s.back();
  s.pop_back();

  // no explicit template parameter on createPowerset. 
  // Type deduction is used here
  powerset<T> pss = createPowerset(s);
  powerset<T> ps = pss;

  for(auto&& i : pss) {
    i.push_back(v);
    ps.push_back(i);
  }
  return ps;
}
```